# WCF Services on Moonlight

Tags: linux, wcf, client, moonlight

Recently my team have been tasked to create a Silverlight (Moonlight) Application, to work on Linux Environments. Our project will try to work both on Windows and Linux.

According to my recent researches (i've done tests too), Moonlight is not compatible with Silverlight 4 yet. Even though this is a bad news for us, since our project was build on Silverlight 4, it's still manageable.

So, this week i've been trying to do some basics server connections with Moonlight and none of it was sucessful. Even with small tests it didn't work. I've built a Silverlight 3 application and tried to push some data through a Silverlight-Enabled Service. It didn't work.Navigation projects won't work either.

Everytime i try to get my data on a Linux host i get an "object reference not set to an instance of a object", which is weird because on Windows Hosts it works fine.

So, i dont know how to pass data through web services (WCF services) on a Linux Client. Can you help me?